# SSRS Subscription date from table

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, subscription

I have a report that has to be sent out on the 2nd working business day of the month so if there is a holiday on the 1st then it sends out on the 3rd.

I am thinking of populating a table with the 2nd business day of the month and run the report from this table.

How would i have the report run on dates values that are in a table below, instead of creating one subscription for each day.

```
  Run Date
  _________
  9/2/2015
  10/2/2015
  11/3/2015
  12/2/2015
  1/4/2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Table or view to determine second Business Day of each month.
2. Create a subscription to your report to run it daily.
3. Next identify the subscription using the following query.

Query is taken from [here](http://bidn.com/blogs/briankmcdonald/bidn-blog/1027/retrieving-report-names-for-ssrs-subscription-jobs).

```
SELECT cat.Name AS ReportName,
        rs.ScheduleID AS JOB_NAME,
        sub.[Description],
        sub.LastStatus,
        sub.LastRunTime
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] cat
        JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions sub
            ON cat.ItemID = sub.Report_OID
        JOIN ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rs
            ON cat.ItemID = rs.ReportID
               AND rs.SubscriptionID = sub.SubscriptionID
 WHERE cat.name = 'YourReportName'
```

4. Go to SQL server agent Jobs and find the subscription with the same name as `JOB_NAME`
5. To view the subscription right click and select properties.
6. Click on the Steps page
7. Click on the edit button of Job-Step list
8. Edit the exec command and add the `if exists` condition to run only if it is first business day of the month.

```
 IF EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM dbo.SecondBusDayTbl
                 WHERE BusDay = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) )
 BEGIN
     EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription'....
 END
```

9. (Optional) One more thing you can do is instead of running daily. Edit the schedule and run only on first 5 or 7 days of the month by creating 5 or 7 different schedules in the schedule step of the subscription sql agent job.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're describing it sounds like [Data Driven Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx) will be the way to go. This allows you to control when reports are sent, to whom and to specify any parameter values needed by populating a table in a database. However this Reporting Services feature is only available with the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server.

If you don't have Enterprise Edition you might need to consider a custom application or doing some VB scripting using the [RS.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx) utility.

Comment: This was the first thing i tried but there was no option to create the custom subscription like i wanted it. Thanks.

Comment: It's a good idea to list the things you have already tried when posting a question, saves time for everybody :)